# A lucky draw system

Tags: database, file, database-design, relational-database

I am creating a lucky draw system whereby the participants' username will be stored in either a file or a database and later one of the username will be picked as the winner. Each product has many participants.

My question is what would be the best way to store the usernames? Should I use a text file with each username separated as username\n ? Should I store the usernames in a field (type text) separated by comma? Or should create a participant table that links the member table and product table?

Comment: if you already have a working database, and these usernames will relate to existing records, then build a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way will be to use a database due to the following reasons

1.Data of such apps may grow beyond control and file ops will take significant time then.

2.Databases ensure easy usage of the data stored,rather than file.

3.Database allows adding of new attributes,which is costly beyond imagination if you use a file.For eg,You may need to add attributes like score to your username in future.

So I would recommend using a table.